# How do I merge System partition with another HFS+ partition without data loss?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

My hard drive is split in three visible partitions: **System**, **Data** and **Backup**.
I'd like to merge **System** (OS X Lion) and **Data** into one partition without data loss.

**Disk Utility** won't let me resize the system partition:

[image: partitions in disk utility]

That's my complete setup:

[image]

Apparently, I can't use `mergePartitions` because [diskutil man](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/diskutil.8.html) says:

> `mergePartitions [force] format name fromDevice toDevice`
>
> Merge two or more partitions on a disk.
> All data on merged partitions other than the first will be lost.

I can imagine decreasing **Data** size, creating a **New** partition, moving all files from **Data** to **New** and proceeding with `mergePartitions`, thus merging **System** and **Data** into **System+Data**. Then I probably can move stuff from **New** to the merged **System+Data** partition and merge them all.

However I'm unsure what will happen to **Recovery HD** that stands between **System** and **Data**. Will it get erased? If so, how can I restore it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There is absolutely no way that you should even *think* about doing any of this without a complete backup on a separate disk. Verify the backup before beginning.**

1) If you have a complete backup, the easiest way to do this would be to wipe everything, make the partitions you want, and then copy the information back from your backup. If your Recovery HD is deleted, there is no way to re-create it without reinstalling the OS. (At least none that I could find when I was searching recently.)

2) Assuming you have a backup *OTHER* than that Backup partition, if you want to attempt to merge these, I would try it in this order:

a. Delete the 'Backup' partition.

b. Merge 'Data' partition and former 'Backup' partition.

c. Merge System partition and other partition.

d. Re-create the 'Backup' partition and restore it from whatever backup you have.

I have done several live-system partition resizings with no problems. However, the one time that there was a problem, I had to reformat the entire drive and start over.

Answer (score 0):

I marked [TJ Luoma](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9226/tj-luoma)'s answer as correct since his approach looks cleaner, however I decided to take a risk and do a live resizing. In case this might help someone plan their own steps, I leave here a list of my actions. They may not be most rational or correct but they worked for me.

**THIS IS TERRIBLY DANGEROUS IF YOU DON'T HAVE A VERIFIED, FULL BACKUP.**

No, really. **You can lose all your data, including the system. Don't do it.**
And this will work **only if Data partition is less than 45% full**.
And I'm not even sure this will work for you anyway.

You have been warned.

---

My steps were as follows:

1. Boot into Recovery HD loader by pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> during the boot.
2. Open Disk Utility, select my HDD and open **Partition** tab.
3. **System** partition now has a resize grip. However it is “blocked” by **Data** partition that comes right after it. I don't have much information on **Data** so I split it equally in two partitions—let's call them **Data A** and **Data B**. **Data A** is large enough to fit everything **Data** contained. **Data B** is empty.
4. Click **Apply**
5. Select the disk (the first root item in left pane), open **First Aid** tab and click **Verify Disk**. Wait for the verification to end.
6. Now we want to move everything from **Data A** to **Data B**. I selected **Data *A*** in the left pane, clicked **Restore** tab and dragged **Data *B*** to the Destination field. Source is **A**, destination is **B**.
7. Click **Restore** and wait for **Data A** to be copied into **Data B**.
8. Again, select the disk (the first root item in left pane), open **First Aid** tab and click **Verify Disk**. Wait for the verification to end.
9. Now you have two identical partitions, **Data A** and **Data B**. The first one prevents **System** from resizing. Open **Partition** tab, select **Data *A*** and click the minus glyph (it may not be visible so I included an image—it's just below the list).

   [image]
10. Select the disk (the first root item in left pane), open **First Aid** tab and click **Verify Disk**. Wait for the verification to end.
11. Go to **Partition** tab and resize **System** so it takes space that was previously owned by **Data A** and now is unallocated. Click **Apply**.
12. Select the disk (the first root item in left pane), open **First Aid** tab and click **Verify Disk**. Wait for the verification to end.
13. Rename **Data B** to just **Data** so your volume name doesn't change.
14. Quit Disk Utility and boot into OS X.
15. Copy whatever data you need from **Data** to **System** (it has enough space now).
16. Check you *really* copied the files you need.
17. Check again.
18. Are you sure?!
19. Open Disk Utility in OS X, remove **Data** and resize **System**.
20. I wish you the best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to merge them.

You can resize partitions right?

Do such a socoban:

1. Make a backup
2. Shrink 'Data' partition (leave just a couple gigabytes free).
3. Enlarge 'Backup' partition so you can put stuff from 'Data' somewhere (at least temporary).
4. Put everything from 'Data' in some folder on 'Backup'
5. Make sure that 'Data' is empty and delete it.
6. Now you must have a lot of free space between 'System' and 'Backup' so you can grow 'System' partition or redistribute space between them as you like :)

Comment: This will not work because a partition's start position is fixed. Shrinking Data partition still wouldn't let me resize the Backup partition “upwards” as it would involve moving the data (which Disk Utility apparently cannot do). However I could shrink Data partition *and* use **unallocated space** for that, [which I did](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/40795/9102).